# How to make Gallery app on Andorid 10 + 11 show image saved to external storage

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-10.0, android-11

So I have the following code:

```
fun saveMediaToStorage(bitmap: Bitmap, context: Context) {
        val filename = "${System.currentTimeMillis()}.jpg"
        var fos: OutputStream? = null
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            context.contentResolver?.also { resolver ->
                val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
                    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, filename)
                    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg")
                    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                }
                val imageUri: Uri? =
                        resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)
                fos = imageUri?.let { resolver.openOutputStream(it) }
            }
        } else {
            val imagesDir =
                    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
            val image = File(imagesDir, filename)
            fos = FileOutputStream(image)
        }
        fos?.use {
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, it)
        }
    }
```

I have the permission in the manifest file:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

As well as the attribute:
`android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

I see the image saved in the proper location when using a FileExplorer app, but the Gallary app doesn't recognize it.

Does anyone notice something that I've done wrong or missed?

Comment: this ***fun is correct*** but shares the code of passing bitmap and context ?

Comment: `As well as the attribute: android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` That is only usefull for Android 10 devices. And not needed using media store.

Comment: For Android 11 devices you should use IS_PENDING twice.

Comment: AFAIK, `image/jpg` is not a valid MIME type. Try `image/jpeg`.

Comment: @Ramesh it is a static function being called from several places. Better than writing the same code all the time.

Comment: @blackapps i'll give it a try